# How can I navigate to a nested Route in React Router Dom V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to open a nested Route from within a nav element.
The App itself runs under /app (as such I redirect any non existing URL to /app).
Within the rendered Layout Component inside the /app Route I'm creating the main navigation as well as the Routes which should ultimately be the content. However once I click on Search or View, the URL gets changed to the correct path, but immediately redirects me to the /app it's as if the Routes "search" and "view" themself were non existent.

Minimal Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-field-ygwbf

App.tsx

```js
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/app" element={<Layout />} />
       <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/app" />} />
    </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Layout.tsx

```js
const Layout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleSearchClick = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some tasks
    navigate("inventory/search");
  };

  const handleViewClick = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some tasks
    navigate("inventory/view");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <button onClick={handleSearchClick}>Search</button>
        <button onClick={handleViewClick}>View</button>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/users">
          <Route path="about" element={<p>example</p>} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/inventory">
          <Route path="search" element={<Search />} />
          <Route path="view" element={<View />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      The content of search / view should now be displayed below the
      Buttons
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The Problem

Take a look at the browser **console**, it shows you:

> You rendered descendant  (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/app" (under ) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate **deeper**, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.

So, the nested routes (deeper navigation according to the documentation) will never render and you cant see the `Search` and `View` sub-routes.

**update** (*Thanks to Drew Reese*):

> in v6 all route paths are always exactly matched, no more path prefix matching like in v4/5. The parent/root paths need to specify the * wildcard so they can now "prefix" match.

##### The Solution

> Please change the parent `<Route path="/app">` to `<Route path="/app/*">`.

So in the `App.tsx`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/app/*" element={<Layout />} />
       <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/app" />} />
    </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Edit on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-nested-routes-v6-8czbj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: This is because in v6 all route paths are *always* **exactly** matched, no more path prefix matching like in v4/5. The parent/root paths need to specify the `*` wildcard so they can now "prefix" match.

Answer (score 1):

you can use
`navigate("view")` instead of `navigate("/view")`
Because:
the root route link is `https://inventory`

- with `navigate("view")` the link would be `https://inventory/view`
- with `navigate("/view")` the link would be `https://view`